# Интеграция LUA в C/С++

Tags: c++, c, lua

Подскажите, вот я прочитал, что "Lua вызывающий C/C ++ и должен скомпилировать C/C ++ в динамическую библиотеку."

У меня такой вопрос - правильно ли я понимаю, что весь код реализации того, что я хочу сделать с тем, что вызвано из Lua - я должен реализовать именно в DLL и никаким образом то, что вызвано из Lua не получится получить именно скажем так в стандартный проект С/С++ - тот который с точкой входа в int main ?

И тот же вопрос про вызовы Lua функий из С/C++, из самого проекта main() - такое нельзя будет реализовать ?

Речь идет именно от выполнении скрипта Lua в стороннем ПО.

Comment: 1) предложение *"Lua вызывающий C/C ++ и должен скомпилировать C/C ++ в динамическую библиотеку."* грамматически неверное 2) dll для вызова из/в lua делать нет никакой необходимости

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо :)   Я статью на инглйиском смотрел переведенную ггул-переводчиком. Но везде пишут, что нужна dll. Возможно я не полностью описал вопрос. Сам скрипт Lua выполняется в сторонней программе.

Comment: в таком случае нужно прилинковать библиотеку `-llua5.3`

Comment: @eri, спасибо, а до функций Lua во внешенем ПО и наборот из внешнего ПО Lua до моего проекта на С++, как добраться ?

Comment: это 2 разных вопроса

Comment: @eri, скорректировал описаение вопроса.

Comment: Ну если это стороннее ПО, то как ваш код попадет в это приложение ? Код в любое приложение попадает либо при его линковке (которая вам очевидно не доступна так как оно стороннее и поставляется видимо уже скопилированным) либо позже, в виде подключаемых на ходу динамических библиотек (dll).

Comment: @Mike, код туда попадает в виде загружаемого Lua скрипта через обычный текстовый файл.

Comment: В таком случае все возможности по выполнению стороннего кода контролирует приложение, выполняющее lua файл и следует искать к нему документацию.

Comment: @Lunar_ Но я так понял, что возможностей самого lua вам недостаточно и необходимо что бы он вызывал некий ваш C/C++ код. вот этот код и должен быть в dll